# Settings file returns escaped string

Tags: c#, string, settings

I am storing an encrypted password using the Settings file in the project. The encryption used is md5, everything up to saving the hash works just fine. When I look in the app.config I can see the correct hash there too. However when retreiving the hash the string has it's characters escaped which makes a comparison not possible

This is the code I use to generate the hash

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
data = x.ComputeHash(data);
String md5Hash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

For testing I put in the text "Test" which generates "\f?f?T\v???8??Za["

When retreiving the password from the settings file I get "\\f?f?T\\v???8??Za["

How to get around this problem?

Comment: Where does it appear escaped? If in Visual Studio while debugging, then this is simply how the visualizer displays them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, *don't do that*. The data returned from `ComputeHash` *isn't* ASCII-encoded text, so you shouldn't be calling `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)`. Prefer `Convert.ToBase64String(data)` - and also prefer hashing using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)`, as otherwise you'll lose data for non-ASCII passwords.

Secondly, I *suspect* that the data isn't really being escaped when you retrieve it - my guess is that you're looking at it in the Visual Studio debugger, and *that's* adding the escaping, rather than it being present in the actual string. Examine the result of `md5Hash.ToCharArray()` to see it one character at a time.

Thirdly, use a better hash than MD5 for passwords :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

I changed the things you mentioned in your first point and the comparison now works fine : )

As for using the MD5 hash, this password is set one time. The app is an offline app running on a computer with no internet. It is really to stop it from being in full plain text view with 'some' strength.