# Path/File name backslash in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm converting from VB to C#, and in C# I seem not to be able to simply write a path string to the application settings..

```
D:\Something  becomes D:\\Something
```

I tried also `@"D:\Something"`, but that also doesn't work.

So what is the correct way? Say I want to have two settings; path and filename. How shall I format them, for the purpose of Path.Combine to make this a valid file-path/name for a database, or in other words, to have single backslashes?

Comment: What didn't work with `@"D:\Something"`?

Comment: can you post the entire path you're converting

Comment: `D:\Something` will sometimes be shown as  `D:\\Something`, there is no indication of a real problem here.

Comment: not sure but VB string had double " instead of one

Comment: @juergend Entering that in application settings gave in code: @\"D:\\Something\"   But it seems the first option works straight, I was confused by an NHibernate exception I thought was related to the path, but was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working correctly - when you read a string with doubled slashes back, they becomes single slashes again. This is called *escaping*. It is designed to let you enter special characters as sequences starting in `\`. Single slash becomes special in this scheme, so you need to escape it with a slash as well.

Comment: So I should enter or save all paths with double slashes?

Comment: @bretddog According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5685344/335858) it works both ways. You do not need to do it, but doing it is OK as well. There is also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8756988/335858) suggesting that escaped strings are often an artifact of looking at the string in the debugger.

Comment: I see, was confused by unrelated exception.